# Getting error "Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'FILEPATH/cccatalog-plugin.php on line 1656"

Tags: plugins, mysql, errors

I'm getting these errors on my Wordpress site:

`Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/89/10848999/html/wp-content/plugins/cc-catalog-plugin/cccatalog-plugin.php on line 1656`

`mysql_connect(): access denied for user 'USER'@'IP' (using password: yes)`

Which is breaking the displaying of data on my database. I have no idea where to start. The googling I did mentioned commands on the localhost but I don't think that's correct for my situation. Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of plugin is that? It's using deprecated functions and also it should use $wpdb instead of its own database handler.

Comment: Its a custom plugin the site owner had created back in 2013. Its a catalog with the ability to print tear sheets (being able to print product details with or without the prices) for dealers to sell to their clients.

Comment: Well, in my opinion that plugin should be updated.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar I've contacted the developer but its been a while so IDK if they're going to be able to help. Any idea how much effort something like this will require?

Comment: It should not be too difficult to update at least the deprecated mysql functions along with the plugin's database handling system.

Comment: Any chance this is easy enough that I could do it myself if the original dev can't/won't help?

Comment: In my case it's `WPML Multilingual CMS` plugin version `2.2.2.1`. I guess it became paid product and so cannot be updated without investing money.